# More sophisticated terminal I/O in Ruby

Tags: ruby, io, terminal, roguelike

I'm trying to make a rouguelike game that runs inside a terminal using Ruby but I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing that. I want to be able to address and update each cell in the standard 80*24 terminal window individually. Can I do this with the standard library or alternately are there any good gems I could do this with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Curses is probably the easiest to implement and it is widely available across platforms. Ruby bindings used to come as part of the standard library, but it's now a gem: `gem install curses`. Here's an example from the docs:

```
require "curses"

def show_message(message)
  height = 5
  width  = message.length + 6
  top    = (Curses.lines - height) / 2
  left   = (Curses.cols - width) / 2
  win = Curses::Window.new(height, width, top, left)
  win.box("|", "-")
  win.setpos(2, 3)
  win.addstr(message)
  win.refresh
  win.getch
  win.close
end

Curses.init_screen
begin
  Curses.crmode
  Curses.setpos((Curses.lines - 1) / 2, (Curses.cols - 11) / 2)
  Curses.addstr("Hit any key")
  Curses.refresh
  Curses.getch
  show_message("Hello, World!")
ensure
  Curses.close_screen
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Gosu](http://www.libgosu.org/).

You can find more alternatives in [ruby toolbox - game libraries](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/game_libraries.html).

I'm assuming you're using a linux. For manipulating the terminal you will need the ncurses library bindings for Ruby. [See ncurses-ruby](http://ncurses-ruby.berlios.de/).

The documentation is sparse, but there are plenty of examples at [this github repository](https://github.com/zdennis/ncurses_examples).

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, I'm more interested in getting my game to output to the terminal, I'm capable of writing the game logic myself.

Comment: I expected that since you wanted rogue like ASCII for the terminal. But was refraining from pointing you in the direction of ncurses. I'd still recommend Gosu over ncurses. Have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that's all the help I needed, also I'm on OS X but I assume the terminal is pretty similar.

Comment: Me too :-). `man ncurses` brings up the man page on Snow Leopard. So you should be fine.